# Why would institutions be interested in an Ethereum ETF

Tags: blockchain

To start, I understand the Bitcoin ETF and why institutions would be interested in trading it. What I don’t understand is an ETF for ethereum or any other crypto. These blockchains provide the rails for NFTs, games, and DEXs. Why would institutions be interested in any of those items? None of them are stores of value. Most of the interest is for crypto enthusiasts looking for web3 experience and decentralization. So why would a centralized system invest in a decentralized system?

Comment: ETFs are investment vehicles. Instutions want ETH ETFs for the same reason they want BTC ETFs: to invest in the underlying asset. You seem to imply institutions only want to invest in stores of value, which is just not true. Most ETFs are *not* stores of value, they are speculative investments

Comment: Thank you for your comment